# How to get the Shadow Case?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have seen a new case in market, Shadow Case (value around 11$) but I don't see anyone getting in game so is there any coin/pass to buy so we can get this case or anything else?

I have read [here](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/category/updates/) little bit info but I did not see anyone getting it, so how to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL/DR** Items are now available for drops and are on the market because some *lucky* people (out of the 300k+ users) have had drops already and are selling the items while the price is high. The price is high because the items are rare at the moment.

---

The [update](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/category/updates/) was released yesterday (17th Sept 2015), and the only way to get your hands on it is either buying one or getting lucky with a drop after a game.

Considering the case was launched around 8 hours ago (so 4-5 hours before your post), I'd say you not seeing one drop isn't an issue, just wait and play more and you'll start to see them drop.

When the Falchion cases were launched, it was a few days before I saw one drop in a game I was playing.

Comment: atleast some line near by answer..thanx mate..but this is not what i am looking for..and m playing from hours..din see anywhere..may be some one knows. thanx for reply

Comment: @Leothelion What *were* you looking for? Your question is a bit hard to read, but this seems to answer at least most of it, if not all.

Comment: @DJPirtu, please read my question and link, as i already said i did not see any guyz but some of are selling then  how did they get means there is way so m just asking for that way..thanx

Comment: @Leothelion You say "i did not see any guyz but some of are selling then". The answer says "just wait and play more and you'll start to see them drop" and "When the Falchion cases were launched, it was a few days before I saw one drop in a game I was playing." You say "there is way so m just asking for that way" and and the answer says "the only way to get your hands on it is either buying one or getting lucky with a drop after a game". Am I missing something?

Comment: @DJPirtu, yes you are missing my line..read back.Tanner said  you can buy from market means some people are selling but then next line tanner said it will start dropping after few days then how these guyz can sell when they are not dropping?? i know i will get case by playing but there are some case like Cobblestone Souvenir Package which you cant get by playing, so like this..hope you get my point.

Comment: @Leothelion I've added update to answer. you're seeing items on the market as some people have received drops. It's random, and you haven't been chosen by Gaben to have an item drop yet. There's no way to force a drop on yourself or your match.

Comment: Well thanx for updated answer..will wait for one day and if i wont fnd then i will choose this as answer..thanx for info.